# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $W$ be a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $V$ be a Finite Dimensional Vector Space and $W$ be a non trivial proper subspace of $V$ then  the linear span $ \langle V- W\rangle $ =$V$?

The statement is true, & the issue here I'm facing to understand this is that if I have removed certain number of dimensions from the Vector Space then how can the linear span is the complete vector space?

For Example for Vector Space $$V = R^3(R)$$consider the subspace, $$ W = \{(x,0,0) ,x \in R\}$$ Now if I subtract this $W$ from $V$ it will make every first tuple $0$. & I will be left with the $(0,y,z)$ type of elements then how can it spans the whole again?

> **My question exactly is:**

What is the meaning of subtraction here in Vector Space? Is this subtraction means to subtract each of the element of $W$ from $V$ i.e.(like we do in Direct Sum)

$$ \langle V- W\rangle =\{(x-y), \text{ } \forall  x \in V  \text{ and }  y \in V \}$$ This is same as **Direct Sum** but the element which was to be added is multiplied by the scalar $-1$ from the field & that seems obvious because there are those elements too in the Vector Space & this makes subtraction exactly same as Direct Sum process.

**Or** it means to remove the element of $W$ which are in V i.e $$ \langle V- W\rangle =\{V-(V \cap W)\}$$
Like subtraction of sets.

If the second one is the definition of subtraction then I think my question is answered but still need explanation how the first definition is not true (Direct sum).

Comment: I believe that $V-W$ could denote the set difference of $V$ and $W$, which is defined as $V-W=\{v\in V:v\notin W\}$. However, it could also denote $V-W=\{v-w:v\in V \text{and} \ w\in W\}$, as you have already pointed out.

Comment: But then my further question : can we say the subtraction between two spaces is same as Direct sum but now the  the element to be added is multiplied by the scalar $-1$ from the field. But this will follow the definition of Direct Sum...?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: You are incorrect in claiming that $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{(x,0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3\}$ consists of the vectors of the form $(0,y,z)$. In fact, it consists of every vector that is not  of the form $(x,0,0)$; that is, it consists of all vectors $(x,y,z)$ in which $y$ and $z$ are *not both equal to $0$*. You are asserting that if you remove the $x$ axis from $\mathbb{R}^3$ you will get the $yz$ plane; but that is not right: you get everything that is not in the $x$-axis.

Comment: Don't yell. Bad enough that you yell your name at us, you shouldn't also yell comments.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what? I just thanked for answering if you are not interested then just ignore what is the point of replying ridiculously? & Same , you too don't yell.

Comment: You replied in all caps. All caps is the internet equivalent of yelling. Your username is in all caps, so you are yelling. Your comment was in all caps, so you were yelling. My reply was not in all caps, so I was not yelling.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay but I was unaware of that. Apologies bro.

Comment: Quote: "With the advent of the bulletin board system, or BBS, and later the Internet, typing messages in all caps commonly became closely identified with "shouting" or attention-seeking behavior, and may be considered rude. Its equivalence to shouting traces back to at least 1984 and before the Internet, back to printed typography usage of all capitals to mean shouting. "(cont)

Comment: (cont) "For this reason, etiquette generally discourages the use of all caps when posting messages online. While all caps can be used as an alternative to rich-text "bolding" for a single word or phrase, to express emphasis, repeated use of all caps can be considered "shouting" or irritating."  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps).

Comment: Okay thanks for the information I'll surely change it to lower case.

Comment: This is trivial is $W=\{0\}$ so let's suppose $W\neq \{0\}$ has dimension $r$.

Extend a basis $\{w_1,...,w_r\}$ of $W$ to a basis $\{w_1,...,w_r,v_1,...,v_k\}$ of $V$.

Set $u_j=w_j+v_1$ for $1\leq j \leq r$ and $u_j=v_{j-r}$ for $r<j\leq k+r$.

Can you show that no $u_j$ is in $W$ and that $\{u_1,...,u_{k+r}\}$ is a basis for $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with direct sums.

Given any two **sets** $A$ and $B$, the difference $A-B$ is the set
$$A-B = \{x\in A\mid x\notin B\}.$$
Here, $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, so in particular they are sets. The difference is the *set theoretic* different,
$$V-W = \{v\in V\mid v\notin W\}.$$

Given a vector space $V$ and a subset $S$ of $V$, $\langle S\rangle$ is the *subspace generated by $S$*; that is,
$$\begin{align*}
\langle S\rangle &= \{ a_1s_1+\cdots +a_ns_n\mid n\geq 0, a_i\in F, s_j\in S\}\\
&= \bigcap_{W\leq V, S\subseteq W} W.
\end{align*}$$

So when you write:

> $$\langle V-W\rangle = \{(x-y)\mid \forall x\in V \text{ and }y\in V\text{[sic]}\},$$

this is wrong, even when we correct the second $V$ to a $W$. That is not what this means.

For an example, consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $W=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then $V$ is the real plane, $W$ is the $X$-axis.

The set $V-W$ is the plane without the $X$-axis. That means it consists of **everything** that is in the plane but is not in the $X$-axis. You are asked to show that the subspace generated by this **set** (which is **not** a vector space, since it cannot contain the zero vector!) is the whole space.

And this is straightforward: we just need to show that every element of $V$ can be written as a sum of multiples of elements of $V-W$. Let $v\in V$. If $v\notin W$, then $v$ is already in $V-W$, hence in $\langle V-W\rangle$.

If $v\in W$, then because $W$ is assumed to be a proper subspace, we know there exists $x\in V$ such that $x\notin W$. Then $v-x\notin W$ (since $v\in W$ but $x\notin W$). And $x\notin W$. Thus, both $v-x$ and $x$ are in $V-W$, and therefore their sum lies in $\langle V-W\rangle$;
$$x = (v-x)+x \in\langle V-W\rangle.$$
Thus, every element of $V$ lies in $\langle V-W\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

The intended meaning of $V-W$ must surely be set difference $\{x\in V\colon x\notin W\}$. (Having it mean the set of differences would be silly here since $V-S=V$ and $V+S=V$ for any set $S$ if $V$ is the ambient vector space.)

Here's a simple proof that $\langle V-W\rangle = V$: it's clear that $V-W\subset\langle V-W\rangle$, so we only have to prove that $W\subset\langle V-W\rangle$. Let $w\in W$ be given. Choose $v\in V-W$, which is possible since $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$. Then $v+w\in V-W$ as well, since if $v+w\in W$ then $v=(v+w)-w$ would be in $W$ as well. Consequently, $w = (v+w)-v \in \langle V-W\rangle$, which is what we needed to show.